# Create a fake RDNS resolution in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, dns, cloud-computing, rdns

I'm currently contributing at Mozilla Community IT, and I'm working with our infrastructure team to setup a puppet master.

Puppet doesn't play nicely without RDNS resolving properly, but our cloud provider (HP) doesn't currently offer RDNS

I was wondering if it's possible to fake an RDNS result, similar to the effect of editing a hosts file for DNS resolution

This question might be completely impossible, but if you have an answer, that'd be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to fake reverse DNS without actually running DNS.

I would recommend running your own DNS server for this, there are many relatively simple solutions.

If you for instance run Unbound or Dnsmasq you can maintain a separate stub zone with your own hosts and reverses and delegate all other queries to the standard resolving DNS servers your provider ... provides :)

This is almost as simple as maintaining an /etc/hosts file, but way more powerful.

http://unbound.net/

http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html